# <cmath> sqrt function cannot be invoked in my function template

Tags: c++, templates, exception, cmath

I'm trying to write a function template that receives a number from stdin as argument and performs a square root operation on it, unless it happens to be negative, in which case an exception will be thrown. The main program looks like this:

```
#include "Sqrt _of_Zero_Exception.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
const T& sqrtNumber(T&);

int main()
{
    int a, result;
    cout << "Enter number to square root: ";
    while (cin >> a){
        try{
            result = sqrtNumber(a);
            cout << "The square root of " << a << " is " << result << endl;
        } //end try
        catch (SqrtofZeroException &sqrtEx){
            cerr << "An exception occurred: " << sqrtEx.what() << endl;
        } //end catch
    }
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
const T& sqrtNumber(T& num)
{
    if (num < 0)
        throw SqrtofZeroException();

    return sqrt(num);
}
```

And this is the header file:

```
#include <stdexcept>

//SqrtofZeroException objects are thrown by functions that detect attempts to square root negative numbers
class SqrtofZeroException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    SqrtofZeroException() //constructor specifies default error message
        : runtime_error("square root on a negative number is not allowed"){}
}; //end class SqrtofZeroException
```

The program can be compiled on Visual Studio but the `<cmath> sqrt` function is greyed out when I try to call it in my `sqrtNumber` function:
[image: greyed out sqrt]

And the output is wrong when I run the program:[image: sample output]

If I change the function template to a normal function that accepts integer arguments, I'm able to call `sqrt` without any issues. So what exactly is the cause of this behavior? Is there something wrong with the syntax of my function template?

Comment: All I get with Clang is an appropriate warning: *warning: returning reference to local temporary object*

Comment: Greyed out is "Intellisence", what error do you get when you try and compile it?

Comment: Just an observation, but your `SqrtofZeroException` isn't thrown when you actually do a sqrt of zero.

Comment: I would consider a negative to be a `std::range_error`, btw

Comment: the signature should be `T sqrtNumber(T num);`  Returning a reference to a local is unsafe so you shouldn't return `const T&`.  Taking the `T&` argument is just a performance hit you don't need.

Comment: @RichardCritten there is no apparent compile-time error as far as I can see. The result however is wrong after I run the program; for instance the square root of 5 becomes 2 for some reason.

Comment: @Streppel fair point, I guess I should probably change the identifier to SqrtofNegativeException

Comment: @RyanHaining could you explain in a bit more why such a reference return might cause security issues?

Comment: it's the same as returning a pointer to something on your stack.  once the function exits, the variable is no longer alive, and the address refers to out-of-bounds memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqrt takes a double as a parameter. It won't let you use templates for that because T can be anything. Since it makes no sense to take the square root of, for example, a pointer, it won't let you use a template for that. Have it take a double, any number can be converted to that.

Comment: If `T` is implicitly convertible to `double`, the call is fine. Type parameters are known at compile-time and checked as normal. [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64f1b7c51dfd274e).

Comment: so I guess I should probably write it as `double sqrtNumber(double)` and not use templates?